# How Bearer tokens (OAuth2) are created?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

I want to know, what is the internal process to encrypt and decrypt a Bearer token used in OAuth2 and the code in Asp.Net Identity.

Once the server receives a token, it is able to retrieve the UserId, Roles, Claims and all properties inside it. So, how are Bearer tokens decrypted? What is encryption algorithm and the code used?

Comment: Check my blog post where I describe how generating tokens taking place, what it depends on, and what is happening when protected resource receives a token. http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh Thank you very much for comment on my question. I've read your post (and all that you write on your blog), but I'm interested on the process of Bearer token encryption. What are the encryption algorithms used and its process. In other words, how Asp.Net Identity is doing this process internally.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you obtaining the token from? Tokens are seldom encrypted (sometimes they are), but they will always be encoded (and signed). OpenID (a protocol on top of OAuth2) uses JWT. OAuth2 (not OpenID) uses "opaque" tokens.

See http://jwt.io for libraries on decoding a JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little Windows Forms [tool](https://github.com/Legends/BearerTokenDeserializer) that decrypts OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens using `MachineKeyDataProtector`.

So if your app is hosted in IIS, then you can use the above tool.

OAuth 2.0 Bearertoken gets:

1. Serialized into binary format
2. MachineKey encrypted (DPAPI is used when app is self-hosted, etc.)
3. Base64 encoded

Comment: Yes indeed, you have to go here: [link](https://github.com/Legends/BearerTokenDeserializer/tree/Initial)

Comment: Hm, ok... it might be helpful to specify that you have a branch called "Initial". I tend to think an empty master branch represents a project that hasn't been started yet.

Comment: Yeah, I've set it to be the default branch now... just a little demo tool..

Answer (score -3):

Here is a short answer, all I have time for. OAuthBearerTokenOptions contains the code needed to create the token. It must be configured in your owin startup.

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

Given that...

```
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expirationMinutes));
string accessToken = oAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```